# Entering payment information in Android Apps

Tags: encryption, tls, android

I'm concerned how android apps that integrate payment processing deal with secure financial information.When purchasing through these apps the apps show the Webpage of the bank asking for credentials.
The page is same as the one which opens when we pay through the Web browser,but there the data is secured by HTTPS.
We never know if the app uses HTTPS and can the app read the password or CC info we enter into the page shown in the app UI.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If the app opens the payment page within the app, there is no way of knowing whether this is actually a HTTPS secured page or whether it is an unsecure site or even just part of the app itself which may grab your details and send them off to the malicious developer of the app.

The same goes for apps that ask for your Facebook details in order to login.

At the end of the day, you have to trust that the app is not tricking you into entering your details.